# Apache: cannot rename server

Tags: apache-2.2

I am currently setting up a server withe apache, but I am very new at this. I wanted to change my server name in the config file, but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried to change the server name using; '`ServerName www.example.com`'

I put the text at the very top of the `httpd.conf` file as there were comments in it, and then I restarted the server, yet it does not work and I get this message:

> `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

I know it's just a warning, but I want to change the name. There is something here I am doing wrong and it's probably obvious, but I really cant seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Changing Apache configuration is not enough. You need to make changes in the DNS to make sure that your new name is tied to your server IP. You can edit your /etc/hosts file to make that change locally.

Comment: You can "hack" your hosts local file to make test during DNS refreshing

Comment: Yes, like given in first reply above... except that afterwards you will forget it and will not understand why it works for you and not for anyone else. So better to fix the DNS right at the beginning in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, to be sure that dns are up to date is imperative.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to `/etc/hosts` file (on local machine):

```
www.example.com <ip-address>
```

If apache is installed on local machine then replace `<ip-address>` with `127.0.0.1`, if it's on remote machine then use machine's IP.